# Select distinct values from substring in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, substring, distinct-values

I'm stuck witn my XSL Transformation. I have this xml code:

```
             <DatoveOblasti>
                    <DataDo Kod="E.01.01.16.01"/>
                    <DataDo Kod="E.01.01.16.02"/>
                    <DataDo Kod="S.05.01.02.01"/>
                    <DataDo Kod="E.01.01.17.01"/>
                    <DataDo Kod="S.05.01.02.03"/>               
            </DatoveOblasti>
```

And I need output like:

```
 <find:filingIndicator contextRef="c">E.01.01</find:filingIndicator>
 <find:filingIndicator contextRef="c">S.05.01</find:filingIndicator>
```

I know how to create substring output but I can't find out how to create it distinct.
I tried this but it's not working.

```
<xsl:template match="DataDo">
    <find:filingIndicator contextRef="c">
        <xsl:variable name="Kod" select="substring(@Kod, 1, string-length(@Kod) - 6)" />
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($Kod)"/>
    </find:filingIndicator>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<DatoveOblasti>
    <DataDo Kod="E.01.01.16.01"/>
    <DataDo Kod="E.01.01.16.02"/>
    <DataDo Kod="S.05.01.02.01"/>
    <DataDo Kod="E.01.01.17.01"/>
    <DataDo Kod="S.05.01.02.03"/>               
</DatoveOblasti>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="DatoveOblasti">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(DataDo/substring(@Kod, 1, 7))">
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <item>E.01.01</item>
   <item>S.05.01</item>
</output>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4HX